# Reapeating a program with a while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, while-loop

I've created a `while True` loop at the end of the program, and a function `repeat()` that checks if it's an empty string which should just restart the program if ran in the loop. Right? I'm not sure if it's version specific or not...

```
import string
import random 

ascii = string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits
punct = string.punctuation

characters = ascii + digits + punct

def repeat():
    check = ""
    if check.upper() == "":
       print(password)

 myList = list(characters)

 random.shuffle(myList)

 passwordraw = myList[:15]
 password = ''.join(map(str, passwordraw))

 while True:
    repeat()
    break
```

Comment: `break` ends the loop. Get rid of it if you want to keep calling `repeat()`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Version specific to what? Have you run the program? What output did the execution produce? Feel free to checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This code makes very little sense. `repeat()` doesn't use any of the variables, it just checks a hard-coded string. None of the code that asks for the password is in the loop, so you won't ask for another password if the first one doesn't pass the check.

Comment: The only thing that's repeated is what's inside the `while` loop. Nothing here restarts the whole program. If you want that, put the whole program inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to clean up the code. The creation of the password boils down to:

```
import random
import string


def main():
    characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)
    random.shuffle(characters)
    password = ''.join(characters[:15])
    print(password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Your description isn't quite clear in what you want to check. For the moment I assume you want the user to enter the password and to repeat the whole process of password generation and the check until the generated password matches the input of the user.

```
def main():
    characters = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)
    while True:
        random.shuffle(characters)
        password = ''.join(characters[:15])
        print(password)
        password_input = input('Enter the password: ')
        if password == password_input:
            break
```

Now you can only leave the loop if you enter the correct random password (with 15 different characters). It's highly unlikely that you are able to do that (that's why I left the `print` in the code) and I'm not sure that this is what you want the program to do. You might want to clarify your question and explain what the "it" in "if it's an empty string" is.

Comment: Thank you I was in a class at the time of posting this and I had been distracted and lost track and then later posted it without adding all the information. Yes this was along the lines of what I had originally wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking out of a `while` loop after calling `repeat()` only once.
Remove the break to continuously call the `repeat()` method in the loop.

Simply just:

```py
while True:
  repeat()
```

Side note: I would add some kind of delay after calling `repeat()`, if that's what you're into. Something like:

```py
# don't forget to import time
import time

# the rest of your code

while True:
  repeat()
  time.sleep(3) # Sleep for 3 seconds
```

Now your program will wait 3 seconds after running `repeat()` again.

Answer (score 0):

A while loop will loop through any code written inside the loop only whilst the parameters are met. in your case whilst true it will be repeated however when false it will not. if you want to change what is looped, change what is inside your loop parameters.